error when re-applying the permissions script into the original database - sql server
when I run the following script:
-- ——— SCRIPT GRANTS for Object Privileges—————

IF OBJECT_ID('[sys].[sysrowsets]') IS NOT NULL   GRANT CONTROL on [sys].[sysrowsets] to [db_myrole_BA]


I get this error message:
Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 271
Cannot find the object 'sysrowsets', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

However:
when I run this:
select radhe=OBJECT_ID('[sys].[sysrowsets]')


My original script comes from here:
-- SCRIPT GRANTS for Objects Level Privilegs
PRINT '-- ——— SCRIPT GRANTS for Object Privileges—————'
SELECT
[GRANTS for Object Privileges]='IF OBJECT_ID(''['+ sys.schemas.name + '].[' + sys.objects.name + ']''' + ') IS NOT NULL ' + CHAR(13) + SPACE(1) +
state_desc + ' ' + permission_name + ' on ['+ sys.schemas.name + '].[' + sys.objects.name + '] to [' + sys.database_principals.name + ']' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
from sys.database_permissions
join sys.objects on sys.database_permissions.major_id = 
sys.objects.object_id
join sys.schemas on sys.objects.schema_id = sys.schemas.schema_id
join sys.database_principals on sys.database_permissions.grantee_principal_id = 
sys.database_principals.principal_id
where sys.database_principals.name not in ( 'public', 'guest')
--order by 1, 2, 3, 5

How is it possible I am getting that error?
I want to save all these permissions, so that when I restore the database - I can re-apply those permissions.




I want to save all these permissions, so that when I restore the database - I can re-apply those permissions.<<< When you restore a database, all the permissions are still there, so you never have to grant smth at the database level, your database is equal to those backed up, permissions included




And here is the answer of how to query hodden system tables: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75365027/sql-server-2019-invalid-object-name-sys-sysrowsets

sys.sysrowsets is a system table and you should enable DAC from 'facets' or sp_configure to reach it.

@MarcelloMiorelli solo uno che non sa che la copia del db ricevuto dal restore e' la copia esatta byte-per-byte del db-origine (tabelle di sistema come sys.database_permissions incluse) ha problemi che non esistono :p

@MarcelloMiorelli If you have the same login on two different servers you should just create the login on the second server with the same sid to avoid this problem

You need to exclude internal tables using is_ms_shipped = 0.

You also need to quote names correctly using QUOTENAME.
You need to handle  WITH GRANT OPTION correctly.
You probably want to add  AS SomeGrantor so that the permissions are chained from the correct original grantor.

SELECT
  [GRANTS for Object Privileges] =
    'IF OBJECT_ID(' COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(o.name) + ') IS NOT NULL
  ' + IIF(perm.state = 'W', 'GRANT', perm.state_desc) + ' '
    + perm.permission_name + ' ON ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(o.name
    + ' TO ' + QUOTENAME(dp.name)
    + IIF(perm.state = 'W', ' WITH GRANT OPTION', '')
    + ISNULL(' AS ' + QUOTENAME(grantor.name), '')
from sys.database_permissions perm
join sys.objects on perm.major_id = o.object_id
join sys.schemas s on o.schema_id = s.schema_id
join sys.database_principals dp on perm.grantee_principal_id = dp.principal_id
left join sys.database_principals grantor on perm.grantor_principal_id = grantor.principal_id
where dp.name COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT not in ('public', 'guest')
  and o.is_ms_shipped = 0;


Charlieface's anwer is the one I am going to accept, it is very good.
The only reason I am posting here, it is because his query did not work on my environment mostly due to COLLATE issues,and I love and use this site as a reference, but as I said his is the answer, with thanks from me.
                        print @@servername + '.' + db_name()
                        SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
                        SET NOCOUNT ON



              SELECT [GRANTS for Object Privileges] =
    'IF OBJECT_ID(' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(o.name) + ') IS NOT NULL ' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
    + IIF(perm.state = 'W', 'GRANT', perm.state_desc) + ' '
    + perm.permission_name + ' ON ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(o.name)
    + ' TO ' + QUOTENAME(dp.name)
    + IIF(perm.state = 'W', ' WITH GRANT OPTION', '')
    + ISNULL(' AS ' + QUOTENAME(grantor.name), '')
                 FROM sys.database_permissions perm         WITH(NOLOCK)
           INNER JOIN  sys.objects o                        WITH(NOLOCK) ON perm.major_id             = o.object_id
           INNER JOIN  sys.schemas s                        WITH(NOLOCK) ON    o.schema_id            = s.schema_id
           INNER JOIN  sys.database_principals dp           WITH(NOLOCK) ON perm.grantee_principal_id = dp.principal_id
      LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals grantor       WITH(NOLOCK) ON perm.grantor_principal_id = grantor.principal_id
                WHERE dp.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT IN ('public', 'guest') 
                  AND o.is_ms_shipped = 0


also from the comments sepupic mentions that "Invalid object name sys.sysrowsets" very useful, recommending DAC:
exec sp_configure 'remote admin connections', 1
go
reconfigure
go

